# any brew install causing 'curl: (35) error:1400410B:SSL routines:CONNECT_CR_SRVR_HELLO:wrong version number'

Tags: homebrew, macos-catalina

I am unable to perform brew install on any formula - and the error in the title.

I am on Catalina 10.15.7, all security updates done.

My curl version:

curl -V
curl 7.64.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin19.0) libcurl/7.64.1 (SecureTransport) LibreSSL/2.8.3 zlib/1.2.11 nghttp2/1.39.2
Release-Date: 2019-03-27
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS GSS-API HTTP2 HTTPS-proxy IPv6 Kerberos Largefile libz MultiSSL NTLM NTLM_WB SPNEGO SSL UnixSockets